# Check for "Value" Types (including types such as strings)

Tags: c#, .net

How can I find out whether a variable can be copied such that changing the original will not affect the copy (and vice versa)?

I thought checking its Type's `IsValueType` property would be enough, but noticed that strings are not considered value types, though a copied string behaves for this purpose, as a value type. Are there any others I have to check for?

**EDIT**

Yes. I realize a `string` is immutable. I just meant that off the top of my head it seemed like `IsValueType` is what I'm looking for. All I want is to be able to have `copy = original` and then never will a change to the variable `original` affect the variable `copy`. This is true for `int`s and `string`s and not for `Form`s for example.

**EDIT 2**

I'm looking for the likes of strings, ints, decimals, Points, enums, Sizes... As opposed to Forms, StringBuilders...

Comment: That depends on how you are cloning? Deep copy or shallow copy?

Comment: @RohitVats Shallow. A simple: `Type1 copy = original;`

Comment: Strings are reference types. They are immutable, so when anyone change it, it will create new instance of string.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Yes. I know. That's why I wrote "a copied string behaves **for this purpose**, as a value type".

Comment: @ispiro: Not quite, as "changing the original" does not actually *change the original* in the case of strings. So, that is unlike what happens with value types. As two rather different things are going on there, it will be difficult to find any automatic way of encompassing all of those types.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You do understand what I'm asking. Right?

Comment: @ispiro: Yes, hence my comment. You want to find a general way to determine whether for any given type, a copy of a variable will be affected to changes to the original.

Comment: Either you misunderstand reference semantics (wouldn't be the first) and think assignment for `string` somehow behaves different from assignment for other reference types, or you're not interested in the notion of a value type but rather in the notion of immutability. The best answer depends on that, so if you could elaborate how you intend to use this knowledge, we could help you better.

Comment: @delnan I don't care about the internal working. (I'll try updating my question.)

Comment: @delnan Question updated.

Comment: @ispiro It really comes down to what you mean by "change to `original`". If you mean the local variable `original`, then the only possible "change" is assigning to it (`original = ...`), and that *never* affects `copy` in any sense of the word, for *all* types (`ref` and `out` parameters nonwithstnading). If "change" includes "calling methods", then the notion you're talking about is immutability, not value-type-ness.

Comment: Concerning the edit: There is no simple automatic way such as an attribute to determine that; it can be true for arbitrary custom types, as well. It depends entirely on whether the methods and properties of the type are implemented to make instances of the type immutable or not.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes. This _might_ be true for any unknown type. I want to find those which are _definitely_ OK. - strings, ints, decimals, Points, enums, Sizes...

Comment: @ispiro: Maybe we need some clarification here: Do you want to get a hand-written list that is true here and now, or do you want to find out how a program could automatically assemble such a list at runtime in its target environment?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper How a program could find that out. (Though, perhaps, this could be done at compile time. I really don't care.)

Comment: @ispiro: Then my statement holds: Other than looking at `IsValueType`, there is no way a program could possibly find out about that. There is nothing in the `System.String` type that guarantees its immutability other than its current implementation.

Comment: Be careful with checking for `IsValueType`. The value would be `true` for `struct`'s but `struct`'s can contain properties of reference types and these won't be copied.

Comment: @AndreasAdler Thanks. Good point.

Comment: System types only I think string is the only reference type that copies.

Comment: @Blam That would be good enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way where you can determine this at runtime for any given type. The only way to accomplish this would be to create collection with all known types that have your desired behaviour. That woould be the built-in value type like `int`, `double` and so on + the reference type `string`.

As I mentioned in the comments you cannot just check for the type's `IsValueType` property because this would be `true` for `struct`'s but `struct`'s itself can contain objects. Consider the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ABC", typeof(string));

        var a = new CustomStruct() { IntValue = 1, DataTable = dataTable };

        Console.WriteLine("IsValueType: {0}", a.GetType().IsValueType);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var b = a;

        a.IntValue = 2;
        a.DataTable.Columns.Add("DEF", typeof(int));

        Console.WriteLine("a.IntValue: {0}", a.IntValue);
        Console.WriteLine("a.DataTable.Columns.Count: {0}", a.DataTable.Columns.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("b.IntValue: {0}", b.IntValue);
        Console.WriteLine("b.DataTable.Columns.Count: {0}", b.DataTable.Columns.Count);
    }
}

public struct CustomStruct
{
    public int IntValue;
    public DataTable DataTable;
}
```

The output is:

```
IsValueType: True

a.IntValue: 2
a.DataTable.Columns.Count: 2

b.IntValue: 1
b.DataTable.Columns.Count: 2
```

So you see, though `CustomStruct` is a value type `b`'s `DataTable` object is the same as `a`'s.

So creating a custom list with know types with the desired behaviour is the easiest way to go.